# How i deploy an Eclipse plug-in into the BIRT Report Manager

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, birt

my question is just like in the topic. I have written an eclipse plug-in (Eclipse 4.3) which do some simple things with the BIRT Engine. When I deploy it into my Eclipse (4.3) which has the BIRT plug-ins installed, the plug-in is visible and it works. However when I try to deploy it to the BIRT Report Desinger it just simply dont start up itself. I tried to change some things in plugin.xml and manifest but without success.

Thanks for any help

P.S. the workbench logfile hasnt reported any Error after deploy

Comment: What "things" you tried to change?

Comment: Well, the goal in the end was do create custom reports, from a source. For now i have commented the whole Birt Code out. My suspicion is that the Report desinger is missing some eclipse core libraries, but i am just opening only `MessageDialog`

Comment: You may try to "Validate Plug-Ins" in the launch config. It may show you the missing plug-ins, if there are missing some.